# Can PostgreSQL use an index for row-wise comparison?

Tags: sql, postgresql, pagination

Let's say that we have the following SQL:

```
SELECT a, b, c
FROM example_table
WHERE a = '12345' AND (b, c) <= ('2020-08-15'::date, '2020-08-15 00:40:33'::timestamp)
LIMIT 20
```

Can PostgreSQL efficiently use a B-Tree index defined on (a, b, c) to answer this query?

To elaborate a little bit on the use-case. This SQL query is part of my cursor-pagination implementation. Since I'm using a UUID as a primary key, I have to resort to using the date/timestamp columns for the cursor, which more closely fits my actual needs anyway. I'm new to PostgreSQL and this row-wise comparison feature, so I'm unsure how I can use an index to speed it up. In my testing using "explain analyze" I wasn't able to make the query use the index, but I assume this may be due to the fact that a table scan is more efficient given that there aren't many rows in the table.

Comment: In `psql`, `set session enable_seqscan=false` to see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it *should* use the index.  But only the first two columns.  It can scan the rows with value of `a` you have specified.  If the index is up-to-date with the table, then Postgres can pull the values of `b` and `c` from the index.  That will allow it to scan a range of values for `b`.